# Enum Type mismatch in Fluent NHibernate (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Table Model:

```
public class UserOwnerShip
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual City City { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual UserRole UserRole { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime RegistryDate { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
internal class UserOwnerShipMap : ClassMap<UserOwnerShip>
{
    public UserOwnerShipMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.IsActive);
        Map(x => x.UserRole).CustomType(typeof(int));
        Map(x => x.RegistryDate);

        References(x => x.User).Not.Nullable();
        References(x => x.City).Nullable();
        References(x => x.Company).Nullable();
    }
}
```

My EnumConvention Class :

```
public class EnumConvention : IUserTypeConvention
{
    public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IPropertyInspector> criteria)
    {
        criteria.Expect(x => x.Property.PropertyType.IsEnum ||
            (x.Property.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
             x.Property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>) &&
             x.Property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0].IsEnum)
            );
    }

    public void Apply(IPropertyInstance target)
    {
        target.CustomType(target.Property.PropertyType);
    }
}
```

And UserRole Enum

```
public enum UserRole
{
    User,
    Operator,
    Manager,
    Manager,
    Admin
}
```

And my nhibernate config section :

```
....().Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<EnumConvention>())
```

So when I query :

```
    IList<UserOwnerShip> userOwnerShip = session.QueryOver<UserOwnerShip>()
                                                    .Where(u => u.UserRole == UserRole.Owner)
                                                    .Where(u => u.IsActive)
                                                    .List<UserOwnerShip>();
```

I got exception:

```
Type mismatch in NHibernate.Criterion.SimpleExpression: UserRole expected type System.Int32, actual type XXX.XXX.UserRole (which is enum type class)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to store the int value of the enum, the mapping is simply:

```
Map(x => x.UserRole).CustomType<UserRole>();
```

There's no need for the EnumConvention.

Comment: The times it is easier than you thought don't make up for the times it  is harder, so enjoy this one.